# return json data from php for emberjs in the right format with $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, ember.js, jsonp

I looked at this [tutorial](http://dev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-into-ember-js-part-3--net-31394)

and tried to create my own php side script to generate json data.

However, I failed on creating a multi-level array.

In the example, a json result of

```
{
  "nextId": null,
  "items": [{
          "title": "Docker, the Linux container runtime: now open-source",
          "url": "http://docker.io",
          "id": 5445387,
          "commentCount": 39,
          "points": 146,
          "postedAgo": "2 hours ago",
          "postedBy": "shykes"
      }, {
          "title": "What\u0027s Actually Wrong with Yahoo\u0027s Purchase of Summly",
          "url": "http://hackingdistributed.com/2013/03/26/summly/",
          "id": 5445159,
          "commentCount": 99,
          "points": 133,
          "postedAgo": "2 hours ago",
          "postedBy": "hoonose"
      },
  ],
  "version": "1.0",
  "cachedOnUTC": "\/Date(1364333188244)\/"
}
```

was generated, I could use `$resultJSON= json_encode($resultArray);` to generate the inner level, which is title, url, id and such, but not 'items' object. I want to know, whether the `items` object comes from the table's name or it is created by encoding a generated array data from an array? 
I use data encoded as json from this php file:

```
$query = "SELECT user_id, username, legacy_id, date_created
FROM eq_user";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$resultArray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$resultJSON= json_encode($resultArray);
echo $resultJSON;
```

The emberjs app will be like

```
App.Item.reopenClass({
  all: function() {
      return $.getJSON("/get_data.php").then(function(response) {
        var items = [];                     
        response.items.forEach( function (item) {
          items.push( App.Item.create(item) );
        });

          return items;
      });
  }
});
```

NOTE: the items is the object I think, but I do not know how it can be generated correctly in php as json data as multi-level array.

Also, one more question, should I use json_encode or not? Because I saw tutorial mentioning that Emberjs uses jsonp... is it a special format? How should I approach this jsonp in PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do

```
 $resultArray = array();
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $resultArray[] = $row;
 }

 $resultJSON= json_encode(array("items"=>$resultArray));
```

Good luck

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP is a technique used to request data from a server in a different domain

Comment: thanks! btw, how to return all the records in that table? I tried several other methods but can never think a right way to work with json, because currently, mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); can only generate one record and can not even be determined which record to generate.

Comment: Wonderful Solution! Thank you so much :)