# Frustration with emberjs data transfering with its backend method as PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, ember.js, ember-data

I tried to do these three simple things but I can not in a world to figure out in almost ONE MONTH already, one word---FRUSTRATION! Now I doubt if emberjs is really worth it...

I want to:

1. Get data from database with just a .php file and data will be in json format

   NOTE: I did this, [in other SO question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791068/return-jason-data-from-php-for-emberjs-in-the-right-format-with-getjson), so I will not repeat.
2. Now, the problem, how can I save those data in a "store" without ember data?
3. Is there any available tutorial on how php can connect with emberjs? I tried to read about its REST adapter, but seem it needs some type of JSON API. Do I need to develop a JSON API if I use pure PHP code as back end?

If anything part is not clear, please reply in comment! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mike B I did that. but then, the data I got from PHP is not really stored in the 'store' and so far all the method to do that is go with ember data, so I am pretty confused...

Comment: It sounds like you're confused on a couple things. It might be beneficial to start with creating a REST JSON API with PHP before you start jumping into Ember/Ember-data. Most of ember backends are with Rails/Rails-API, but I'm sure you can find a simple tutorial on writing a REST API with PHP if you good around. Good luck!

Comment: @Gowie47 thanks for the great suggestion, I was super confused on many terms that emberjs described. How long usually one may need to take to understand emebr/emberdata if one has experience with jQuery (1 year ) and php (1 year)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chen, to be honest it is very easy to handle data without ember-data . I have used it few times, some of which were related to building quite large front-end systems. Main reason, ember-data was not that stable at the time and did not inspire much confidence. The other reason is that as you will see it is pretty straightforward.

All you have to do is create a class (it is also nice to have a singleton ember controller) that will get data from the server and post data to the server. The data format should be JSON, to make all process easier and clearer. You achieve this by using simple ajax calls,

```
function retrieveData(callback){
jQuery.ajax({
            url: *yoururl*,
            timeout: ajaxTimeOut,
            success: function(data){
/* here you store this data somewhere
it could be helpful to have a callback that you call so that this class/controller
is not coupled with specific logic*/
                if(callback!=null){
                    callback(data);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

The function for retrieving data can be called when the associated route gets called or from the controller of that route. The callback function passed to the previous class/controller will set the data retrieved to some properties of the controller, or it could even be its model. Simple example,
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/AsOcAbU/1/edit

**js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  /*model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  },*/
  setupController:function(controller,model){
      this.controllerFor('myJSON').findJSONData(function(data){
        controller.set('model',data);
      });
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

});

App.MyJSONController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  findJSONData:function(callback){
    var data = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];/*this will come from the server with an ajax call i.e. $.ajax({...})*/
    if(callback){
      callback(data);
    }
  }

});
```

**hbs**

```
   <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

        {{outlet}}
      </script>

      <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
      {{#if model}}
        <ul>
        {{#each item in controller}}
          <li>{{item}}</li>
        {{/each}}
        </ul>
        {{else}}
        loading ....
        {{/if}}
      </script>
```

In the context of complete application you will probably need to iterate the json data and create ember objects out of it. That is really simple as well thanks to ember,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oWetaDuH/1/edit

```
/*let's say you retrieve color objects from php*/

 findJSONData:function(callback){
  setTimeout(function(){

   /*this will come from the server 
     with an ajax call i.e. $.ajax({...})*/
    var data = [{color:'red'}, {color:'yellow'}, {color:'blue'}];

    if(callback){
      callback(data);
    }

  },2000);//mimic ajax call
 }

/*and you need to use ember magic bindings, so you have your own objects to represent the domain model*/
App.MyColor = Ember.Object.extend({
  color:null
});

/*then the code for retrieving will become*/

setupController:function(controller,model){
  this.controllerFor('myJSON').findJSONData(function(data){
        var myColors=[];
        data.forEach(function(jsonColor){
          myColors.pushObject(App.MyColor.create(jsonColor));/*this is all you need to create the ember object !!*/
        });
        controller.set('model',myColors);
      });
  }
```

and **hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{#if model}}
    <ul>
    {{#each item in controller}}
      <li>{{item.color}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
    {{else}}
    loading ....
    {{/if}}
  </script>
```

**update**

If it is required to pause routing until the model is resolved, then `promises` should be used as explained in the guides

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/asynchronous-routing/

In this case, since `jQuery` `ajax` function returns a promise, the previous example could look like,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mogicira/1/edit

**js**

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model:function(controller,model){
      return    this.controllerFor('myJSON').findJSONData(function(data){
        var myColors=[];
        data.forEach(function(jsonColor){
          myColors.pushObject(App.MyColor.create(jsonColor));
        });
     return myColors;
      });
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

});

App.MyJSONController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  findJSONData:function(callback){
    return $.ajax({url:""}).then(function(data){

          data = [{color:'red'}, {color:'green'}, {color:'blue'}];

    if(callback){
       return callback(data);
    }

    });
  }

});
```

Comment: Wow... this seem like a very very detailed answer thank you so much first! btw, I have been troubling to understand the purpose of 'callback' variable in findJSONData. What is the usage of it? Why would need to use it to call the data? Is 'callback' variable in this case, a function that convert data into html code since you are checking if it exist or valid in the function? I am rather new in jQuery, bare with me :) Thank you!

Comment: @Chen yes that's what it is. The callback is a function to which the data from the ajax response is passed. You could directly write the code related to the data i.e. start creating color objects, however this way you decouple the code that does the communication/ajax with the code that does the parsing of json to ember objects.

Comment: @Chen moved the `settimeout` that mimics the ajax call more accurately to the `findJSONData` function that would actually make the ajax call.

Comment: Hum, so basically we are not able to leverage the store? Since I did not see any store is been used in your example as well... That's sad... actually I was looking forward for this store feature. Does it mean I have to write API if I want to use the store?

Comment: @Chen the store and everything described in the models section of emberjs guides is related to ember-data. So if you do not want to use ember-data (which i thought that was the question), then you basically manage data yourself as i have shown.  As you can see it is not difficult, but it always depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it:) Because I was trying to leverage their catching on the store to speed up the site on reload and caching up the information that I will just preloaded into the localadapter or something similar... I have a logic about how to do it, but just this lack of actual coding examples drive me nut big time... Guess I will need to forget about the using of store for now, at least not until EmberData grow a beard... Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 2):

If you like ember & ember-data it should be for the less-code and code maintenance between other not less important concerns

If you feel comfortable with php, move your php code to a modern FrameWork for not reinventing the weel and in order to obtain similar benefits that ember done to your front-end

I'm developing an ember app feeded with Codeigniter http://ellislab.com/codeigniter and codeigniter rest service https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver **but I don't recommend you this combination**

I my opinion you should try Laravel http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/laravel-4-a-start-at-a-restful-api/ or directly go to Rails/Rails-API

Comment: Thanks for the analysis! Do you think its a great learning curve to move into Rails? Since I have been reading about article about its difficulties on launch and much greater learning curve than PHP. How long would you think someone has knowledge of entry level PHP will manage to handle Rail? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think so, I think learning rails is like learning symphony or zend, or ember... Reading code examples and documentation, learning conventios and coding, coding, coding

Comment: You can also consider the Slim framework (http://www.slimframework.com) for PHP REST calls. It is very light.